When does a Markov Chain reach its stationary distribution?
Consider a markov chain $\{X_j\}_j$. For simplicity, assume that the chain is time homogeneous, that is,
$$p(X_j=x|X_{j-1}=y)=P_{xy}$$
in that the transition probabilities are fixed over time.  Further assume the existence of a (unique) stationary distribution $\pi$: $$\pi(x) = \sum_{y} P_{xy} \pi(y)$$
Question: When is it guaranteed a Markov Chain achieves its stationary distribution? That is, when is $X_j\sim \pi$ for some $j$?
Is it sufficient that the Markov Chain is ergodic, that is $P^r>0$ for some $r$?
Motivation Naively, I want to say that the stationary distribution will be reached because the distribution of $X_j$ keeps changing until it reaches $\pi$. However, it seems like there can a priori be cases where there's periodicity: $X_j\sim \pi_0$, $X_{j+1}\sim \pi_1$, $X_{j+2}\sim \pi_0$ (and neither distribution is the stationary distribution), or cases that the $X_j$ tend toward a limiting distribution but never reach it.
Edit: Follow up Question When can we guarantee the R.V. $X_j$ converge in distribution to $\pi$, even if they never reach it?

I think the Markov chain will get closer and closer but (in most cases) never reach it exactly.

What about the periodicity case?

In the periodic case, there is no stationary distribution, it basically traverses its orbit time and time again.

The transition matrix has to be a solution to $A^j=A^{j+1},$ so $A$ must have only $0$ and $1$ for eigenvalues.

I suppose that assumes the Markov process is "connected" in some sense - that from the start state, you have non-zero probality of reaching any other state.

@gt6989b In the periodic case, there is still a stationary distribution (namely the average of the distributions in the cycle).
